# Inserting data from text area into database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want to insert data from text are into database but what I want is every line of text are should occupy a new row in the database. e.g

> number one
>   number two
>   number three

this is the content of the text area and should be inserted into three different rows of the table.

Comment: Do you know how to insert data into a database? If so, prove to use that you have attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's `explode()` to split the textarea's content up at each line break. So something like:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $textarea_content);
```

`$lines` will then be an array.